# Ajax link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading informacia.html into a div with ajax, then I change the history by pushState

```
<div id='ajax-accept'>

  </div>

  <div id='menu-wrap'>
    <div id='menu'>
      <div id='main' class='category-holder'>ГЛАВНАЯ</div>
      <div id='about-us' class='category-holder'>О НАС</div>
      <div id='catalog' class='category-holder'>КATAЛОГ</div>
      <div id='info' class='category-holder'>ИНФОРМАЦИЯ</div>
      <div id='contacts' class='category-holder'>КОНТАКТЫ</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
$('#info').click(function(){
   $('#ajax-accept').load('http://beardhouse.com.ua/sources/pages/o-nas.html');
   history.pushState({}, 'about us', "o-nas");
});
```

All work's good, but when I try go to link , for example this http://beardhouse.com.ua/o-nas - it's just not fount.

Why it's happend and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your not providing enough source code for anyone to see the problem, where us the link in question? you should try to recreate the issue in jsfiddle.  Also, when I go to the link posted I get a 404 error, so it may have nothing to do with your code

Comment: @QBM5  okey, give me few minutes

Comment: I don't understand which link works and which don't please rewrite your question since I get lost and don't know how to help you. Have you tried `console.log("something")` when you fire `click` event and see what happens?